# Parsing XML and cast elements to a typed collection using LINQ, C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, collections

I have an XML doc:

```
<statuses>
  <status>
  </status>
  <status>
  </status>
</statuses>
```

I have parsed this into an XDocument, and want to use LINQ to select the elements into a strongly typed collection of Status classes (all status elements are simple types, either string or int).

Any ideas how I can do this?

Thanks!

Comment: any example of the xml you are working with?

Answer (score 4):

With `XDocument`, something like below:

```
    class Status
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
    static void Main()
    {
        string xml = @"<xml>
<status id='1'><text>abcdef</text></status>
<status id='2'><text>ghijkl</text></status>
<status id='3'><text>mnopqr</text></status></xml>";
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

        var list = (from el in doc.Root.Elements("status")
                   select new Status
                   {
                       Id = (int)el.Attribute("id"),
                       Text = (string)el.Element("text")
                   }).ToList();
    }
```

Note that `XmlSerializer` would also be a possibility here - reducing the amount of code you need to write and maintain.

Comment: Small suggested edit: using ' instead of " for attribute values means you don't need to quote anything :)